# Different operation per each row on multiple columns in python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having pandas dataframe like this

```
A    B    D    E
2    12   1    2
3    54   1    4
10   2    1    1
```

I would like to multiply values in C and D column by the value in A, but keep values in B column. So from the dataframe above, the result I would get would be :

```
A    B    D    E
2    12   2    4
3    54   3    12
10   2    10   10
```

However, I have many columns I want to modify, not just 2 like in the example. Therefore I would like to know what is the most efficient way to do this.

I was looking at DataFrame.assign function but with that, it seems like I can only modify 1 column at the time.

Thanks !

Comment: Won't `df[col_list] * df['A']` just work?

Comment: Inspired by DSM's solution I tried a little modification fo yours as `df.loc[:,col_list] = df[col_list] * df['A']` and surprisingly it got me NaNs in all the col_list columns. I wonder why, the datatype in both col_list collumns and "A" columns are numpy.float64

Comment: Hmm, I think there is some issue with the broadcasting here, try this: `df[col_list] = df[col_list].mul(df['A'], axis=0)`

Comment: Basically it looks like the broadcasting is happening along the wrong axes resulting in some funny df filled with `NaN` values returned, if you did this then it would work: `(df[col_list].T * df['A']).T` but this isn't so pretty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never know what do with "most efficient" questions.  But if you want that output, you could use `mul`:

```
>>> df.loc[:,["D","E"]] = df[["D","E"]].mul(df["A"], axis=0)
>>> df
    A   B   D   E
0   2  12   2   4
1   3  54   3  12
2  10   2  10  10
```

where you could replace `["D","E"]` by `list_of_columns` so you wouldn't have to repeat the column names.